# QML Resize Jitter and Poor drag performance

Tags: windows, qt, qml, qtquick2

i am just starting with QML and am facing two issues at the moment.

The first one is, that even when i start a new project and do not add anything, i get terrible performance when resizing the window:
[image: Resize Problem]

I have only created a new Qt Quick Project using Qt 6.5, i have tried the msvc and the mingw version of Qt..

The second problem i'm facing is lag when dragging a rectangle:
[image: Drag Lag]

The code for the second problem looks as follows:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        height: 100
        width: 100
        color: "orange"

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: For the resizing part, check if this is happening in other programs as well, I think it's unrelated to Qt. However, for the dragging part, it's not normal. Please check your *task manager* and monitor how many resources your program is using. You can also run your program in *profiling mode*.

Comment: What type of Windows device do you have? You can tweak the display by setting the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable to "desktop", "angle" or "software"? For more info, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-graphics.html

Comment: Tested both parts on my Windows machine. I do not notice the same, everything is running smooth.

Comment: @SMR: I just wanted to say that the resize problem is specific to my own builds.
But it does also happen when resizing chrome. Weirdly on e.g. windows explorer or OBS Studio (that is using Qt i think) it does not happen.
I had a look at the resource monitor and it shows that the application uses about 2% of the cpu when i drag the rectangle around.

Comment: @Stephen Quan: I use a thinkpad, more specific a t490s. But i have to say that i use a lenovo thunderbolt dock for my screen. Changing the QT_OPENGL variable did not change the outcome.

Comment: @Jüprgen Lutz: Thanks for trying, that at least confirms that it is not a general Qt problem, but something with my setup.

Comment: With the resize issue, we can "hide" the problem if you change Window to ApplicationWindow and, assigning your Rectangle to the background property. This will ensure that the background is always white and black is never showing.

Comment: @MichaelHübler it is also worthwhile to review your graphic software / drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same issues as follow:

1. Flickering by resize of Window (black/white) as shown in question
2. Move&Drap not smooth/delayed
3. Resize of Window result in very unsmooth rendering of QtQuick Window

My specs:
OS: Windows 64Bit
CPU: Ryzen 5 7600X
Graphics Card: NVIDIA RTX4070TI
Qt6.5.2 + MSVC2019

I tested this steps:

1. Updated Qt 6.5.0 -> Qt6.5.2 Result: Same (flickering etc.)
2. Changed main.cpp to set environmentvariable `qputenv("QSG_INFO", "1" );`

QSG_INFO

```
qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.68 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.68 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: Creating QRhi with backend D3D11 for window 0x247a40d27e0 (wflags 0x1)
  Graphics API debug/validation layers: 0
  Debug markers: 0
  Prefer software device: 0
  Shader/pipeline cache collection: 1
qt.rhi.general: FLIP_* swapchain supported = true, ALLOW_TEARING supported = true
qt.rhi.general: Default swap effect: FLIP_DISCARD
qt.rhi.general: Adapter 0: 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti' (vendor 0x10DE device 0x2782 flags 0x0)
qt.rhi.general:   using this adapter
qt.rhi.general: Adapter 1: 'AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics' (vendor 0x1002 device 0x164E flags 0x0)
qt.rhi.general: Adapter 2: 'Microsoft Basic Render Driver' (vendor 0x1414 device 0x8C flags 0x2)
qt.scenegraph.general: Created QRhi 0x247a42f14d0 for window 0x247a40d27e0
qt.scenegraph.general: MSAA sample count for the swapchain is 1. Alpha channel requested = no.
qt.scenegraph.general: rhi texture atlas dimensions: 1024x512
```

3. Changed main.cpp to use RHI backend opengl by `qputenv("QSG_RHI_BACKEND", "opengl");`

The new QSG_INFO

```
qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.68 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.68 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: Creating QRhi with backend OpenGL for window 0x2259261d7e0 (wflags 0x1)
  Graphics API debug/validation layers: 0
  Debug markers: 0
  Prefer software device: 0
  Shader/pipeline cache collection: 1
qt.rhi.general: Created OpenGL context QSurfaceFormat(version 4.6, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(DeprecatedFunctions), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize 8, greenBufferSize 8, blueBufferSize 8, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QColorSpace(QColorSpace::SRgb, QColorSpace::Primaries::SRgb, QColorSpace::TransferFunction::SRgb, gamma=2.31), profile  QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile)
qt.rhi.general: OpenGL VENDOR: NVIDIA Corporation RENDERER: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 VERSION: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 537.13
qt.scenegraph.general: Created QRhi 0x22592841080 for window 0x2259261d7e0
qt.scenegraph.general: Attempting to seed pipeline cache for QRhi 0x22592841080 from xxx
qt.rhi.general: Seeded pipeline cache with 1 program binaries
qt.scenegraph.general: MSAA sample count for the swapchain is 1. Alpha channel requested = no.
qt.scenegraph.general: rhi texture atlas dimensions: 1024x512
```

Here the full main.cpp for reference

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qputenv("QSG_INFO", "1" );
    qputenv("QSG_RHI_BACKEND", "opengl");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/untitled1/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Update:**

This is currently my workaround above. Looks like other people encounter very similar issue.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/144011/qt-6-4-windows-movement-resizing-behavior-on-directx/4